# Allocate an integer randomly across k bins

Tags: python, random

I'm looking for an efficient Python function that randomly allocates an integer across `k` bins.
That is, some function `allocate(n, k)` will produce a `k-sized` array of integers summing to `n`.

For example, `allocate(4, 3)` could produce `[4, 0, 0]`, `[0, 2, 2]`, `[1, 2, 1]`, etc.

It should be randomly distributed per item, assigning each of the `n` items randomly to each of the `k` bins.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny thanks, this is the best solution! I'll accept it if you want to enter it as an answer.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny I entered this as a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71891419/1840471

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapting Michael Szczesny's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71888628/allocate-an-integer-randomly-across-k-bins?noredirect=1#comment127034648_71888743) based on numpy's new paradigm:

```py
def allocate(n, k):
    return np.random.default_rng().multinomial(n, [1 / k] * k)
```

[This notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1LG6vb-aigJN-rddQXG3E1Nw_oF8Yv1Py#scrollTo=Z7sP5209VuEd) verifies that it returns the same distribution as [my brute-force approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71888629/1840471).

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for a uniform distribution across all possible allocations (which is different from randomly distributing each item individually):

Using the "stars and bars" approach, we can transform this into a question of picking k-1 positions for possible dividers from a list of n+k-1 possible positions. ([Wikipedia proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)#Theorem_two))

```
from random import sample

def allocate(n,k):
    dividers = sample(range(1, n+k), k-1)
    dividers = sorted(dividers)
    dividers.insert(0, 0)
    dividers.append(n+k)
    return [dividers[i+1]-dividers[i]-1 for i in range(k)]
    
print(allocate(4,3))
```

There are ((n+k-1) choose (k-1)) possible distributions, and this is equally likely to result in each one of them.

(This is a modification of Wave Man's solution: that one is not uniform across all possible solutions: note that the only way to get [0,0,4] is to roll (0,0), but there are two ways to get [1,2,1]; rolling (1,3) or (3,1). Choosing from n+k-1 slots and counting dividers as taking a slot corrects for this. In this solution, the random sample (1,2) corresponds to [0,0,4], and the equally likely random sample (2,5) corresponds to [1,2,1])

Comment: Thanks, I added a new question for this variant, hope you'll submit this there! https://stackoverflow.com/q/71890816/1840471

Answer (score 2):

This should be faster than your brute-force version when n >> k:

```
def allocate(n, k):
    result = np.zeros(k)
    sum_so_far = 0
    for ind in range(k-1):
        draw = np.random.randint(n - sum_so_far + 1)
        sum_so_far += draw
        result[ind] = draw
    result[k-1] = n - sum_so_far

    return result
```

The idea is to draw a random number up to some maximum `m` (which starts out equal to `n`), and then we subtract that number from the maximum for the next draw, and so on, thus guaranteeing that we will never exceed `n`. This way we fill up the first k-1 entries; the final one is filled with whatever is missing to get a sum of exactly `n`.

Note: I am not sure whether this results in a "fair" random distribution of values or if it is somehow biased towards putting larger values into earlier indices or something like that.

Comment: Thanks, interesting approach. I'd like to see its fairness before using though.

Comment: `Counter(tuple(allocate(4, 3)) for _ in range(1000))` to see that `(4,0,0)` or `(3,1,0)` occurs far too often.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a brute-force approach:

```py
import numpy as np

def allocate(n, k):
    res = np.zeros(k)
    for i in range(n):
        res[np.random.randint(k)] += 1
    return res
```

[Example:](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1LG6vb-aigJN-rddQXG3E1Nw_oF8Yv1Py?usp=sharing)

```py
for i in range(3):
    print(allocate(4, 3))
```

> [0. 3. 1.]
> [2. 1. 1.]
> [2. 0. 2.]

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution. I think it will make all possible allocations equally likely, but I don't have a proof of that.

```
from random import randint

def allocate(n,k):
    dividers = [randint(0,n) for i in range(k+1)]
    dividers[0] = 0
    dividers[k] = n
    dividers = sorted(dividers)    
    return [dividers[i+1]-dividers[i] for i in range(k)]
    
print(allocate(10000,100))
```